# Angular JS Использование одной директивы несколько раз

Tags: javascript, angularjs

```
Memoris.controller('Flats', ['$scope', '$http',Flats])
.directive('dropzone', ['$location', '$http', dropzone]);

Memoris.controller('Tours', ['$scope', '$http', '$routeParams',Tours])
.directive('dropzone', ['$location', '$http', dropzone])
```

Сама директива

```
function dropzone($location, $http) {
    return {
        restrict: 'C',
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            var config = {
                url: 'tour/add-tour',
                maxFilesize: 100,
                paramName: "file",
                maxFiles: 10,
                maxThumbnailFilesize: 100,
                parallelUploads: 50,
                autoProcessQueue: false,
                autoDiscover: false,
                uploadMultiple: true,
                addRemoveLinks: true,
                params: scope.formData,
                dictDefaultMessage: "Перетащите фото",
                init: function () {
                    var self = this;
                    setTimeout(function () {
                        if (scope.formData.img) {
                            scope.imgFromServer = true;
                        }

                        $.each(scope.formData.img, function (i, v) {
                            var mockFile = {name: v};
                            self.emit("addedfile", mockFile);
                            self.emit("thumbnail", mockFile, "/images/" + v);
                            self.emit("complete", mockFile);
                        });

                    }, 1000);
                }
            };

            scope.files = [];
            var eventHandlers = {
                'addedfile': function (file) {
                    scope.file = file;

                    if (file.status == 'added') {
                        scope.newfile = true;
                    } else {
                        scope.files.push(file.name);
                    }

                    scope.$apply(function () {
                        scope.fileAdded = true;
                    });
                },

                'removedfile': function (file) {
                    var index = scope.files.indexOf(file.name);
                    scope.files.splice(index, 1);
                },

                'queuecomplete': function (e) {
                    if (!scope.imgFromServer) {
                        scope.formData = {};
                        scope.$apply();
                        dropzone.removeAllFiles();
                    }

                },

                'error': function (file, response) {

                }

            };

            dropzone = new Dropzone(element[0], config);

            angular.forEach(eventHandlers, function (handler, event) {
                dropzone.on(event, handler);
            });

            scope.resetDropzone = function () {
                dropzone.removeAllFiles();
                scope.formData = {};
            };

            scope.updateTour = function () {
                scope.formData.img = scope.files;

                $http({
                    url: "/tour/update-tour",
                    method: "POST",
                    data: scope.formData
                }).success(function (data) {
                    //console.log($scope.formData);
                }).error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                    scope.status = status;
                });
            };

            scope.updateTourWithNewPhoto = function () {
                dropzone.options.url = 'tour/update-tour-with-new-photo';
                scope.formData.img = scope.files
                dropzone.options.params = scope.formData;
                dropzone.processQueue();
            };

            scope.addTour = function () {
                dropzone.options.params = scope.formData;
                dropzone.processQueue();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Хочу использовать директиву *dropzone* несколько раз, но выдает ошибку

> Dropzone already attached.

Comment: ну так а что мешает использовать ее дважды? Функция _directive_ - создает директиву - зачем вы хотите создавать ее несколько раз. если вам нужно ее использовать?

Comment: Покажите пример пожалуйста!

Comment: сотрите второй вызов `.directive('dropzone', ['$location', '$http', dropzone])` и все заработает

Comment: Мне нужно, что бы директива была видна из разных контроллеров

Comment: директива никак не связана с контроллерами. Больше того - контроллер не имеет доступа к директиве, никак

Comment: приведите пример вашего кода, и как вы хотите использовать _директиву в контроллере_

Comment: Внутри директивы используются переменные из контроллеров

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/38775/discussion-between-grundy-and-ruslik).

Answer (score 2):

Директивы в AngularJs подключаются к модулю и только к нему. 
Хорошая практика создавать модуль для директивы:

```
angular.module('my-directive', []).directive('myDirective', [funciton(){..}]);
```

В модуле где нужно ее подключить просто передаем ее как зависимость:

```
var pageApp = angular.module('page-app', ['my-directive']);
```